# Converting Json to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am trying to write a game that uses javascript. I am generating a list of words from a database and I have encoded the php using json_encode, and then echoed it into a javascript variable but it doesn't appear to be working, not sure what the issue appears to be.

I have also tried parsing the variable with no luck.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT word FROM `words` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,2300";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $json_array = array();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $json_array[] = $row;
        }
        $tmp = json_encode($json_array);
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

?>

//Javascript
function print() {

    var tmp = <?php echo $tmp ?>;
    document.write(Object.values(tmp));

}
```

I want to store the result into an array in javascript that is like:

array = ["word1","word2",...]

Then I can call like array.pop and get the word on the top.

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in generated html?

Comment: Currently it prints nothing.

Comment: So, debug your code to find out why. `var_dump($tmp)`.

Comment: My bad actually prints: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...

Comment: What were you expecting instead? `Object.values(tmp)` returns an array of objects. `document.write()` converts that to a string, and when you convert an object to a string you get `[object Object]`.

Comment: Try `document.write(JSON.stringify(Object.values(tmp)))`

Comment: Or maybe you should just return an array of words from PHP, instead of an array of rows. Use `$json_array[] = $row['word'];`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others this is due to referencing the object, you need to reference the value you want inserted into the array. You can print out the array to confirm this works:

```
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        words.push(Object.values(tmp)[i].word);
    }

    for(i=0; i < words.length; i++){
        document.writeln("word is: " + words[i]);
        document.writeln();
    }
```